# jQuery Validation - how to separate errors within the errorPlacement callback?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

```
 errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
 $('#div').append(error.html()); 
 }
```

I want to append a list of errors within a div in my webpage upon calling this function. Right now I am just calling error.html() which is giving me the whole list of errors listed within the messages function concatenated together.

Ex in the div:

> Title is requiredNumber of words must be between 50 and 65Picture is
>   Required

I can provide more code if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`errorPlacement` is the option/function used to place each individual error next to each individual input field.  This is not the option to use if you want a list of errors.

If you want to create a list of error messages, then you would use [the `showErrors` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors).  Refer to [the documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#showerrors) for example usage...

```
showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
    $("#summary").html("Your form contains "
    + this.numberOfInvalids()
    + " errors, see details below.");
    this.defaultShowErrors();
}
```

**Generic DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/0k0vL1b0/**

If you want to suppress the messages next to each field, simply comment out the `this.defaultShowErrors()` line and write some code to extract the messages from the provided `errorList` argument.

**DEMO 2:  http://jsfiddle.net/0k0vL1b0/1/**

Comment: this.defaultShowErrors is giving me *undefined*. Can there be any reason for this? I have included your function in the proper place

Comment: @BDillan, I am not seeing any such errors with that code:   http://jsfiddle.net/0k0vL1b0/